# load year database to datetimepicker year only c#

Tags: c#, forms, datagridview, datetimepicker

i have two form. form1 show books data, and form2 to edit the books data... in form2, i have datetimepicker with custom format "yyyy" (year only) to update the books publish year.... so when i load the form 2 datetimepicker not show the book publish year but it show 2012 (current year)...

txttahun (is the datetimepicker name)

this is my code when form2 load and show the data from form1

```
DateTime elshose;
        bool elshoseOkay;
        elshoseOkay = DateTime.TryParse(Data["tahunterbit"].ToString(), out elshose);
        if (elshoseOkay)
        {
            txttahun.CustomFormat = "yyyy";
            txttahun.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
            txttahun.Text = elshose.Year.ToString();
        }
        this.TopMost = true;
        txtkode.Text = Data["kodebuku"].ToString();
        txtkode1.Text = Data["kodebuku"].ToString();
        txtjudul.Text = Data["judulbuku"].ToString();
        txtpengarang.Text = Data["pengarang"].ToString();
        txtkategori.Text = Data["namakategori"].ToString();
        txtpenerbit.Text = Data["penerbit"].ToString();
        //txttahun.Text = Data["tahunterbit"].ToString();
        txtstok.Text = Data["stokbuku"].ToString();
        tglter.Text = Data["tglpenerimaan"].ToString();
```

so how to make the datetimepicker show the books publish year i input ?

Answer (score 0):

May be in your case DateTime.TryParse will always fail. debug and see whether your application come to the line where you set Text for `txttahun`

if you using `dateTimePicker.Text` property you need to give proper date time string. otherwise it will fail.

since `elshose` is DateTime object you can directly assign it as `dateTimePicker1.Value`

```
dateTimePicker1.Value = elshose;
```

or

```
txttahun.Text = elshose.ToString();
```

run below code and check what you get as year.

```
    DateTime elshose;
    txttahun.CustomFormat = "yyyy";
    txttahun.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
    if (DateTime.TryParse(Data["tahunterbit"].ToString(), out elshose))
    {
        txttahun.Text = elshose.ToString();
    }else
    {
       // this line only for testing....
       txttahun.Text = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-5).ToString();
    }
```